# Windows Form App Changing the data in a data grid view based on a Combo box selection

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Sorry I'm relativley new to Visual and learning for school but I can't work out how to change the data displayed in a Data Grid View based on a selection in a combo box.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use the `Filter` property of the datagridview's `BindingSource` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example with LINQ and `List(Of Producer)`(**_allProducers**) assigned to DataSource of the DataGridView (**grdProducers**) and ComboBox(**cmbProducers**)

```
Class Producer
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property NAME As String
    Public Property COMPANY_ID As Integer
End Class

Private _allProducers As List(Of Producer) = New List(Of Producer)
```

Fill `_allProducers` List:

```
_allProducers = {
      New Producer() With {.ID = 1, .NAME = "John", .COMPANY_ID = 2},
      New Producer() With {.ID = 2, .NAME = "Sam", .COMPANY_ID = 3},
      New Producer() With {.ID = 3, .NAME = "Smith", .COMPANY_ID = 2},
      New Producer() With {.ID = 4, .NAME = "Dan", .COMPANY_ID = 1}
    }.ToList()
```

Init ComboBox:

```
cmbProducers.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
cmbProducers.DataSource = _allProducers
cmbProducers.DisplayMember = "NAME" 'value to display in combo
cmbProducers.ValueMember = "COMPANY_ID" 'value to return
```

Now you can set `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the `cmbProducers` ComboBox. This event occurs when the SelectedIndex property has changed.

```
Private Sub cmbProducers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbProducers.SelectedIndexChanged
    if (IsNumeric(cmbProducers.SelectedValue)) Then 'check for numeric values
      grdProducers.DataSource = _allProducers.Where(Function(p) p.COMPANY_ID = cmbProducers.SelectedValue).ToList()
   EndIf
End Sub
```

In this case `_allProducers` `List` will be filtered and will return all objects which `COMPANY_ID` is equal to the value selected in the ComboBox.
I hope this can help you.